# How do you type a mixed parameter in PHP strict mode?

Tags: php, oop

I am injecting a [Memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) class in a custom one.

The [Memcached::set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php) method has a ["mixed"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.mixed) pseudo-type.

[PSR-6: Caching Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6/) is not strictly typed.

How do you do it with [strict-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) as PHP does not allow overloading?

```
Class Cache
{
  private Memcached $cache;

  [...]

  public function __construct(Memcached $cache) { [...] }

  public function set(string $key, ???? $value, int $expiration): bool
  {
    return $this->cache($key, $value, $expiration);
  }

}
```

PS: And today, the php team has accepted the union type for php8 which will solve that ([wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2)):

> "[...] We've held off on adding a mixed type out of fear that it would
>   be used in cases where a more specific union could have been
>   specified. Once union types are supported, it would probably also make
>   sense to add the mixed type [...]"

Comment: Mixed is not a strict type, therefore I don't get the point of typing it, or I'm missing something.

Comment: I am speaking about the question marks in the code.

Comment: ok, mixed type is not a strict type by definition, you cannot type it there. You just leave the type blank = mixed. Is this answering your question?

Comment: As @Jimmix pointed out, you can't type-hint a mixed type. You have to leave your parameter without any type-hint, no matter if `strict_type` is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP < 8, there is no other way to declare a parameter being of "mixed type" (as in, accepting any type of value, be it scalar, reference, a class instance, or even null) than by **omitting** the type hint.

This says you expect a `string` for `$key`, an `int` for `$expiration`; and any value whatsoever for `$value` (e.g. 'mixed').

```
public function set(string $key, $value, int $expiration): bool
```

`declare(strict_type=1)` has no bearing on this. That declaration only has an effect regarding scalar type declarations, where they exist. If there is no type declaration, the type is `mixed`, and there can't be any kind of "type coercion", which makes `strict_types` moot.

Note that a [proposal existed to introduce this pseudo-type declaration](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed-typehint), but it never got past the draft stage, since [it didn't get a particularly warm reception](https://externals.io/message/101371) at the PHP internals group.

---

Since PHP 8+, you can type-hint as `mixed`, which is equivalent to `array|bool|callable|int|float|null|object|resource|string`

[RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mixed_type_v2).

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.mixed.php).

Comment: Hopefully they will introduce method overloading with strict_type=1 in a future php version.

Comment: @Toto
Your prayers are being heard.
Since version 8 it is possible to type hint it with the mixed keyword.
I'm looking forward what will come in future.